# Reduce polygon area by percentage

Tags: javascript, algorithm, polygon

I have a polygon that consists of points (x,y). What I woul like to do is to reduce this by a percentage.
Keep in mind: I dont want to just scale it. The polygon should get a kind of inner border (its width depends on the percentage) that gets cut off the polygon.

Who knows an algorithm that can achieve that?

Input: Array of Points, Percentage

Output: Array of Points

[image]

Comment: Can the polygon be concave? If yes, what should be the result of scaling a polygon "Z" (width << size) by 50%?

Comment: The polygon has no restrictions related to the form. The processed polygon should cover 50% of the area of the previous polygon.

Comment: So, in "Z"-50% example, simply cutting the bottom half will suffice? Or there are some other constraints?

Comment: No, cutting the bottom half is not what i am looking for :D I want to cut out a inner consistent border (that covers exactly my percentage).

Comment: Sorry 50% was just an example.

Comment: @HighPerformanceMark If you scale "Z" shape by 50%, it won't fit within initial shape, your method works mostly for convex polygons. For even worse example, take "double hourglasses" with two arbitrarily narrow bottlenecks - it can't be reduced by making inner border of fixed width, either.

Comment: I added a picture, so you can see how its mend to work for convex and concave polygons.

Comment: Also: Before you can actually subtract the 'border' from the polygon you have to calculate the width of the border (how thick is the border when you want to reduce by x%?)...

Comment: I think you might be looking for an algorithm which behaves like Sketchup's *offset tool*. The problem is that this algorithm reduces the number of vertices when the paths of two vertices cross. Don't know if that is allowable for you.

Comment: Most GIS softwares implement *inward-* and *outward-buffering*.  You might find what you are looking for in the literature on those topics, or by inspecting the source code of an open-source GIS.  Another approach would be to look into *morphological erosion* as applied to vector-based data sets.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you seek is the *offset polygon*. It is not easy to compute,
but it has been quite well-studied.
Perhaps the answer to this earlier question could help:
[Shrink polygon to a specific area by offsetting](https://mathoverflow.net/a/150072/6094).

---

[image]

---